# Hibernate session requires fully qualified class name, despite explicit entity name

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 6, and I have some code I've been porting that uses Session.get with an entity name and identifier.  We do a lot of reflection, and there's some other background, so this may look a bit odd and explicitly passing the entity name may seem superfluous, but it's necessary for us.

The entity name by itself doesn't work, it seems to require the fully qualified name:

```
@Entity(name = "Root")
...
session.get("Root", rootId); // doesn't work

session.persist("Root", root); //works...???
```

For the session.get, I end up with a

```
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: Root
```

However,

```
session.get("mypackage.fully.qual.Root", rootId); // works
```